# convert number to string using javascript

Tags: javascript

The code below converts a number to a word. But the issue is if the input value is having some value example 1. still it's showing "Here The Numbers Printed".
on change its changing value. If by default it's having value it's showing that in word format.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var th = ['', ' thousand', ' million', ' billion', ' trillion', ' quadrillion', ' quintillion'];
    var dg = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
    var tn = ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'];
    var tw = ['twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];

    function update(){
        var numString =   document.getElementById('number').value;
        if (numString == '0') {
            document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'Zero';
            return;
        }
        if (numString == 0) {
            document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'messeg tell to enter numbers';
            return;
        }

        var output = toWords(numString);
        //print the output
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = output;
    }

    function toWords(s) {
        s = s.toString();
        s = s.replace(/[\, ]/g, '');
        if (s != parseFloat(s)) return 'not a number';
        var x = s.indexOf('.');
        if (x == -1) x = s.length;
        if (x > 15) return 'too big';
        var n = s.split('');
        var str = '';
        var sk = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            if ((x - i) % 3 == 2) {
                if (n[i] == '1') {
                    str += tn[Number(n[i + 1])] + ' ';
                    i++;
                    sk = 1;
                } else if (n[i] != 0) {
                    str += tw[n[i] - 2] + ' ';
                    sk = 1;
                }
            } else if (n[i] != 0) {
                str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
                if ((x - i) % 3 == 0) str += 'hundred ';
                sk = 1;
            }
            if ((x - i) % 3 == 1) {
                if (sk) str += th[(x - i - 1) / 3] + ' ';
                sk = 0;
            }
        }
        if (x != s.length) {
            var y = s.length;
            str += 'point ';
            for (var i = x + 1; i < y; i++) str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
        }
        return str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    }
    </script>

    <input name="data[Customer][customer_budget_from]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="From" required="required" autocomplete="off" maxlength="255" id="number" size="70" onkeyup="update();" onkeydown="return (event.ctrlKey || event.altKey 
                        || (47<event.keyCode &amp;&amp; event.keyCode<58 &amp;&amp; event.shiftKey==false) 
                        || (95<event.keyCode &amp;&amp; event.keyCode<106)
                        || (event.keyCode==8) || (event.keyCode==9) 
                        || (event.keyCode>34 &amp;&amp; event.keyCode<40) 
                        || (event.keyCode==46) )" type="text" value="1">
    <div id="container">Here The Numbers Printed</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

first of all：

```
 var numString =   document.getElementById('number').value;

 typeof numString //string
```

so `numString == '0'` and `numString == 0` is the same.

you should use `'numString === '0'` or `numString === 0`  instead